# Excel Advanced Filter Unique Values on a Filtered List

Tags: excel, vba

Is there away using Excel Advanced Filter to filter for unique values on column where the rows have already been filtered on other columns?

Basically, I have a worksheet where other columns are using autofilter with their own criteria, and then finally I want to filter out duplicate values on this one column. However, when using Advanced Filter on this one column it is undoing all my filtering on the other columns. Now, I now when using the duplicate filter in data that I can avoid this problem, but it permanently deletes data on that column. I do not wish to lose data, I just wish to hide it - copy the final result to my other worksheet - and keep the original source.

Is there away of hiding duplicates without losing other filtering?

Comment: I have but not always I am receiving replies!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you're trying to do, not that I know of. I think instead of advanced filtering first then copying the result to your other worksheet, you'll need to copy the filtered columns to your other worksheet without filters, then do your advanced filter in there to get your final result (then copy again to yet another sheet to remove the new filter again if necessary). Copying and pasting from one sheet to another removes the filter in the new sheet. Wouldn't that work for you?